Left justify the given equation
Question: How can I justify (on the left side) the given equation?
MWE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\left(u\,\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v\,\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)
        &=  \left(\dfrac{k_{2}}{\rho\,c_{p}}\right)\,\dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}+\left(\dfrac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho\,c_{p}}\right)\,\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 
        + \left(\dfrac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho\,c_{p}}\right)\;u^2 \\[1ex]
        &\qquad\qquad\quad\quad\quad\qquad\qquad  -\dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\;\dfrac{\partial q_{r}}{\partial y} +q'''
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


(note: there are two ways to interpret the linked question, see my answer there for explanation)

Off-topic: width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm may be expressed more succinctly as margin=1cm.

@Mico Thanks for correcting me. I request you for left justification of my equation.

It's not clear why to push one equation to the left margin: either none or all of them. The latter choice is obtained by specifying the fleqn document class option.
Anyway, I present (with a narrower text width) a few ways you could do.
Note the simplifications to the input and the omission of several \, tokens (and the wrong \;). In two cases I even added \!: when \right) is immediately followed by \left( and in the exponent.
A facility for partial derivatives makes the input much more readable.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

Just the last term on the next line
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \pder{T}{t}+\left(u\,\pder{T}{x} + v\,\pder{T}{y}\right)
  =
  \left(\frac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\pder{^2 T}{y^2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\!\left(\pder{u}{y}\right)^{\!2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho c_{p}}\right) u^2
  \\[1ex]
  {}-
  \dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\pder{q_{r}}{y}+q'''
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Just the last term in the next line, but pushed a bit to the left
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \pder{T}{t}+\left(u\,\pder{T}{x} + v\,\pder{T}{y}\right)
  =
  \left(\frac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\pder{^2 T}{y^2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\!\left(\pder{u}{y}\right)^{\!2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho c_{p}}\right) u^2
  \\[1ex]
  {}-
  \dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\pder{q_{r}}{y}+q''' \qquad
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Two terms in the next line
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \pder{T}{t}+\left(u\,\pder{T}{x} + v\,\pder{T}{y}\right)
  =
  \left(\frac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\pder{^2 T}{y^2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\!\left(\pder{u}{y}\right)^{\!2}
  \\[1ex]
  {}+
  \left(\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho c_{p}}\right) u^2
  -
  \dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\pder{q_{r}}{y}+q'''
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

A more conventional set up
\begin{multline}
  \pder{T}{t}+\left(u\,\pder{T}{x} + v\,\pder{T}{y}\right)
  =
  \left(\frac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\pder{^2 T}{y^2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\!\left(\pder{u}{y}\right)^{\!2}
  \\[1ex]
  +
  \left(\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho c_{p}}\right) u^2
  -
  \dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\pder{q_{r}}{y}+q'''
\end{multline}

A more conventional set up with just one term on the next line
\begin{multline}
  \pder{T}{t}+\left(u\,\pder{T}{x} + v\,\pder{T}{y}\right)
  =
  \left(\frac{k_{2}}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\pder{^2 T}{y^2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho c_{p}}\right)\!\left(\pder{u}{y}\right)^{\!2}
  +
  \left(\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho c_{p}}\right) u^2
  \\[1ex]
  -
  \dfrac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\pder{q_{r}}{y}+q'''
\end{multline}

\end{document}



It will be great help to me Thanks a lot.

Given rather narrow margins are in use, I can't see a good argument for splitting the equation across two lines. To align this equation (and all other equations) to the left, I suggest you specify fleqn as a document class option. Oh, and I'd also get rid of the unnecessary tall parentheses.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}
     +\left(u\,\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} 
          + v\,\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)
    = \frac{k_{2}}{\rho\,c_{p}}\, \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}
      +\frac{\mu+\kappa}{\rho\,c_{p}} 
         \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^{\!\!2} 
      +\frac{\sigma B_{0}^2}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,u^2 
      -\frac{1}{\rho\,c_{p}}\,\frac{\partial q_{r}}{\partial y} 
      +q'''
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Thanks again but the issue is according to margin of my documents it doesn't fit in a single line. Can you share split option? I hope you will understand my problem.

@SandyM Compiling the document as you provided, and removing the split and all the \quads results in an equation that fits in one line (no overfull warning). This is even before cleaning up the extra parentheses as Mico suggested. // If you insist on having the lines split, you have to tell us exactly what sort of output you are looking for, per user202729's comment.

@WillieWong you are provided code will compile actually I have been writing a chapter and it is one the equation of it. Chapter margin is different. That is why I am searching for split option.

@SandyM - If margin=1cm is not applicable to your real document, why did you specify this option (or, rather, a bunch of options that may be simplified to margin=1cm) in the test document you provided?

@Mico Yes you are right.
